# Como validar controles vacios?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flutter

Quiero validar que mis controles no tengan campos vacios con un AlertDialog, e creado una funcion que valida campos vacios pero igual me sigue permitiendo ingresar campos vacios y no me carga mi AlertDialog,

```
def agregar(e):
        
        
        lista = [codpro, nompro, ddcate, ddpeso]
        
    
        if not lista:
            mostrar_mensaje(e) 
        else:
        #   agregar 
            tablaproducto.rows.append(
                DataRow(
                    cells=[
                        DataCell(Text(codpro.value)),
                        DataCell(Text(nompro.value)),
                        DataCell(Text(ddcate.value)),
                        DataCell(Text(ddpeso.value)),
                        DataCell(
                            Row([
                            IconButton("delete", 
                                    icon_color ="red",
                                    on_click = eliminar,
                                        ),
                            IconButton("create", 
                                    icon_color ="blue",
                                    on_click = editar
                                    ),    
                                ])
                            ),
                    ]
                )
            )
```

Intente poniendo el If not pero aún asi me sigue permitiendo ingrersar dato vacios